# How to convert records including 'include' associations to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

If I do something like:

```
result =  Appointment.find( :all, :include => :staff )
logger.debug { result.inspect }
```

then it only prints out the Appointment data, and not the associated staff data.
If I do result[0].staff.inpsect then I get the staff data of course.

The problem is I want to return this to AJAX as JSON, including the staff rows. How do I force it to include the staff rows, or do I have to loop through and create something manually?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`:include` is an argument for `to_json`, not `find`. What you need to do in your controller is this:

```
def return_json
  @appointment = Appointment.find(:all)
  respond_to { |format|
    format.json { render :json => @appointment.to_json(:include => :staff) }
  }
end
```

You need to setup an association between Appointment and Staff for this to work.

Comment: :include is an argument to both ActiveRecord::Base#find and ActiveRecord::Serialization#to_json. They do different things: #find(:include) loads the associated data in one or more SQL queries, instead of the dreaded N+1 queries. #to_json(:include) marks one or more associations for inclusion in the returned JSON object. #to_xml behaves the same way.

Comment: @AlexKorban thank you! if staff similarly has a parent that you want to include in the JSON how would you include that? Basically I want to get: '@appointment.staff.manager.name

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ActiveRecord::Serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001873) and [ActionController::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000658) (see section: "Rendering JSON")

```
def show
  @appointment = Appointment.find(:all, :include => :staff)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render :json => @appointment.to_json(:methods => [:staff]) }
  end
end
```