# ruby converting query with associations to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to store the results of a model and an association in a variable like so:

`data = Sale.all.includes(:book)`

However, all this does is store active record objects for `Sale` in `data` with no data on the associated `Book` (each `Sale` `has_one` `Book`)

So, I tried:

```
Sale.all.includes(:book).map |sale|
  puts sale.book
  puts sale
end
```

Which gives me exactly what I'm looking for. However I need all of this store inside of `data` variable.

What is the best way to get the sale data along with the book data (for each sale) into some sort of hash or JSON or XML?

Hope I'm explaining this well enough

Comment: What do you want the structure to look like? Would you expect a nested hash? If you just do `data.to_json`, do you not get the `Book` included?

Comment: Precisely, all I get are the columns from `Sale`, none of the data from its `Book`

Comment: but `sale.book` inside of `map` returns all the records for each `sales` `book`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567642/how-to-convert-records-including-include-associations-to-json  I forgot that `to_json` can take an `:include` parameter to get associations, but I don't know if I have ever tried it on a collection rather than a single object.  `data.to_json(:include => :book)`

Comment: Ah, thanks! Looks like a dupe. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: You can delete it if you want to, but if it gets closed it will serve as a signpost to the existing question in searches.

Comment: try: `hash = Sale.all.includes(:book).reduce({}) {|hash,sale| hash[ sale.book ] = sale }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `as_json` that returns a Hash and accepts some additional serialization options.

```
data = Sale.all.includes(:book).as_json(include: [:book])
```